# Интеграция ресурсов в приложение

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, рефлексия, resources

У меня есть приложение с разными темами и мне нужно как-то получать к ним доступ. Самым подходящим для меня является файл ресурсов. Элементы разных тем, конечно, повторяются. Но как мне получать доступ к отдельной теме? Интерфейс получения темы выглядит вот так:

```cs
object GetThemaElement(string thema, string elementName)
{
    //Реализация...
}
```

Тут есть два пути:

1. 1 файл ресурсов
2. n файлов ресурсов, где n - кол-во тем

Но к обоим этим подходам есть претензии:

1. Если назвать элемент `[имя темы]_[имя элемента]`, то единственный способ получить к нему доступ - рефлексия, а хочется обойтись без неё (уверен, есть пути по-лучше).
2. Если у нас имя отельного файла является именем темы (или `Resources.[имя ресурса].resx` - не важно), то единственный способ обратится к ресурсу - файловая система, а хотелось бы обойтись без привязки к файлам (юзается привязка к дизайнеру).

---

Как решить проблемы этих путей и/или есть ли другой(-ие) пути решения этой проблемы?

Comment: хм... а как ты собираешься работать с ресурсами?  если тебе нужна файловая система

Comment: @Grundy я в конструкторе ресурсов ссылаюсь на др. файлы. При этом автоматически создается файл `[имя ресурса].Designer.cs`, внутри которого есть класс `[имя ресурса]`. В последнем содержатся свойства - данные, хранящиеся в самом файле ресурсов. В коде мы юзаем дизайнер, который уже юзает файловую систему сам, но инкапсулированно, через класс `ResourceManager`. Мне не нужна файловая система на прямую.

Comment: Скажите, а темы можно загружать / удалять? Ваш вариант на мой взгляд подходит только в статическом случае.

Comment: похоже у тебя не совсем верное представление о том как работают рексурсы

Comment: @РамазанАлисханов Нет. Кол-во тем изменяемо.

Comment: @Grundy Т. е. вы используете старые подключения к ресурсам с помощью оператора `using`? Или через `ResourceManager`?? Или как?

Кстати, что это за _рексурсы_ такие)?

Comment: Вы что-то путаете, ресурсы (напрямую) никак не связаны с файловой системой, хотя конечно, можно хранить файл .resources и в файловой системе. Никакого "второго способа" нет, к ресурсам, созданным через дизайнер, также доступ может осуществляется через рефлексию.